# GRASP Indirection vs Mediator Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, grasp

What is the difference between GRASP Indirection and Mediator Pattern? I've tried googling but did not find the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GRASP Indirection](https://books.google.ca/books?id=r8i-4En_aa4C&lpg=PP3&ots=mX3CKYypIZ&dq=allintext%3AAssign%20the%20responsibility%20to%20an%20intermediate%20object%20to%20mediate%20between%20other%20components&pg=PP3#v=onepage&q=allintext:Assign%20the%20responsibility%20to%20an%20intermediate%20object%20to%20mediate%20between%20other%20components&f=false) seeks to avoid direct coupling:

> Assign the responsibility to an intermediate object to mediate between other components ... so that they are not directly coupled.

So, you could argue that GRASP Indirection is a big inspiration for the Mediator pattern. But, you also can find it in other patterns, such as Adapter.